# Insert Inline Image Programatically in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm developing a SwiftUI app, where I want to insert inline image into `Text` view. For static content, I may use string interpolation like this:

```swift
Text("Hello, \(Image(systemName: "pencil")) World! \(Image(systemName: "pencil.circle"))")
```

The result would look like:

[image]

But in my case, the content may be dynamic. That is, I may receive the following string from server:

```
Hello #image(pencil) World! #image(pencil.circle)
```

I must parse the content dynamically and present the inline image with SwiftUI Text. Is this possible? I only wonder how to construct the string interpolation with image dynamically, the parsing of string is not my concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite an interesting problem!
Here is an alternate way of achieving this.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let serverString = "Hello #image(pencil) World!     #image(pencil.circle)"
        
        parse(serverString).reduce(Text("")) { (result, model) in
            return result + model.getSwiftUIView()
        }
    }
    
    func parse(_ serverString: String) -> [Model] {
        serverString.split(separator: " ", omittingEmptySubsequences: false).compactMap {
            Model(word: String($0))
        }
    }
}

struct Model {
    enum ViewType {
        case image, text
    }
    
    let type: ViewType
    let content: String
    
    init(word: String) {
        if word.hasPrefix("#image") {
            type = .image
            content = Model.replaceImagePatterns(input: String(word))
        } else {
            type = .text
            content = word
        }
    }

    func getSwiftUIView() -> Text {
        if type == .image {
            return Text("\(Image(systemName: content))") + Text(" ")
        } else {
            return Text(content) + Text(" ")
        }
    }
    
    static func replaceImagePatterns(input: String) -> String {
        let pattern = "#image\\((\\w+(?:\\.\\w+)*)\\)"
        let replacement = "$1"

        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
            let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: input.utf16.count)

            var modifiedString = input
            let matches = regex.matches(in: input, options: [], range: range)
            for match in matches.reversed() {
                if let range = Range(match.range, in: modifiedString) {
                    let matchedString = String(modifiedString[range])
                    let modifiedMatchedString = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: matchedString, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: matchedString.utf16.count), withTemplate: replacement)
                    modifiedString = modifiedString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: modifiedMatchedString)
                }
            }

            return modifiedString
        } catch {
            print("Error creating regex: \(error)")
            return input
        }
    }
}
```

**Input**

`Hello #image(pencil) World!     #image(pencil.circle)`

**Output**

[image: iPhone 14 Pro Simulator]

I hope you find the answer helpful.

Comment: I use custom images instead of the system ones and the images and text are not vertically centered. Do you have how can I fix that ? Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a variable to the `Image` when you initialize it:

```
var imageNameFromServer = "pencil"
Text("Hello, world \(Image(systemName: imageNameFromServer))")
```

---

Update: Example of using many `Text` items:

```
@ViewBuilder
var longText: some View {
    (0...100).reduce(Text(""), { $0 + Text("\($1)")})
}
```

Comment: But this does not solve the problem. The position where I should insert image is also dynamic.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to say anything about that. How is the position determined?

Comment: Consider the following example: I want to repeat "Hello, \(Image(systemName: "pencil")) " for 100 times, without using HStack or VStack, just Text. Is it possible to do this programmatically, instead of writing a long string interpolation?

Comment: Yes. You can concatenate `Text` `View`s in SwiftUI. IE `Text(...) + Text(...)`. I've updated my answer to show using a `reduce` function to do this.